# Image preview with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do multiple input image preview with jQuery. Previewing the image works fine, but the image preview in same div, I need each image preview in different div. How can I do it?

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <form action="index.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     desktop:<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br/>
          <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
      mobile:<input type="file" id="mobile" name="mobile" multiple><br/>
          <div id="selectFiles"></div>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form></br></body>
</html>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*multiple image preview first input*/

    $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

   selDiv = $("#selectedFiles");
   $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

   $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

   /*end image preview */

   /* Multiple image preview second input*/
   $("#mobile").on("change", handleFileSelect);

   selDivM = $("#selectFiles");
   $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

   $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

  /*end image preview*/
)}
```

**Methods**
function for Handle File Select

```
var selDiv = "";
var selDivM="";
var storedFiles = [];

function handleFileSelect(e) {
   var files = e.target.files;
   var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
   filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

    if(!f.type.match("image.*")) {
        return;
    }
    storedFiles.push(f);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
     var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\"       data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
        if ( typeof selDivM !== "") {
            selDivM.append(html);
        }else {
            selDiv.append(html);
        }

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
});

}
```

function for Handle Form

```
function handleForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();

for(var i=0, len=storedFiles.length; i<len; i++) {
    data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
        alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
    }
}

xhr.send(data);
}
```

function for remove file if clicked

```
function removeFile(e) {
   var file = $(this).data("file");
   for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
    if(storedFiles[i].name === file) {
        storedFiles.splice(i,1);
        break;
    }
}
$(this).parent().remove();
}
```

[see code pen snippet](http://codepen.io/noushid/pen/XXgmwX)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*multiple image preview first input*/

    $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

    selDiv = $("#selectedFiles");
    $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

    $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

    /*end image preview */

    /* Multiple image preview second input*/
    $("#mobile").on("change", handleFileSelect);

    selDivM = $("#selectFiles");
    $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

    $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);
 });
    /*multiple image preview*/


var selDiv = "";
// var selDivM="";
var storedFiles = [];

function handleFileSelect(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
    filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

        if(!f.type.match("image.*")) {
            return;
        }
        storedFiles.push(f);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
             selDivM.append(html);
          }
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    });

}

function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();

    for(var i=0, len=storedFiles.length; i<len; i++) {
        data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
            alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
        }
    }

    xhr.send(data);
}

function removeFile(e) {
    var file = $(this).data("file");
    for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
        if(storedFiles[i].name === file) {
            storedFiles.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
#selectedFiles img {
            max-width: 200px;
            max-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        #userActions input{
            width: auto;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #selectFiles img {
            max-width: 200px;
            max-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
   <form action="index.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     desktop:<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br/>
          <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
      mobile:<input type="file" id="mobile" name="mobile" multiple><br/>
          <div id="selectFiles"></div>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you receive the data for image src ?

Comment: You can use inside your function `handleFileSelect(e)` to get the name like `e.target.name` this will return `files` or `mobile`. Based on that you can append it to a div as you wish.

Comment: Hello, I just Wanted to know how the remove functionality works here? Its not working for me with my code. Does that require Handler.cfm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on your snipped.... create a div of preview based on the device type

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*multiple image preview first input*/

  $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

  selDiv = $("#selectedFiles");
  $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

  $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

  /*end image preview */

  /* Multiple image preview second input*/
  $("#mobile").on("change", handleFileSelect);

  selDivM = $("#selectFilesM");
  $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

  $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

  console.log($("#selectFilesM").length);
});
/*multiple image preview*/


var selDiv = "";
// var selDivM="";
var storedFiles = [];

function handleFileSelect(e) {

  var files = e.target.files;
  var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
  var device = $(e.target).data("device");
  filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

    if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
      return;
    }
    storedFiles.push(f);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='" + f.name + "' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";

      if (device == "mobile") {
        $("#selectedFilesM").append(html);
      } else {
        $("#selectedFiles").append(html);
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  });

}

function handleForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0, len = storedFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
    data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
      alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
    }
  }

  xhr.send(data);
}

function removeFile(e) {
  var file = $(this).data("file");
  for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
    if (storedFiles[i].name === file) {
      storedFiles.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
#selectedFiles img,
#selectFilesM img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#userActions input {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
#selectFiles img,
#selectFilesM img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  desktop:
  <input data-device="desktop" type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
  <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
  <br/>mobile:
  <input data-device="mobile" type="file" id="mobile" name="mobile" multiple>
  <br/>

  <div id="selectedFilesM"></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You achive this as **following code snippet**

```js
$("#fileUploadInput").change(function(event){
    $("#filePreviewImage").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileUploadInput" type="file">
<img id="filePreviewImage" src="" alt="The image preview" height="90" width="160">
```

Just replace `"filePreviewImage"` with `your custom selector` and it will populate the preview regardless of div. *Enjoy* ...

Comment: this is single image preview, i need multiple image preview.

Comment: you are using multiple file inputs???? what do you mean by multiple image preview

Comment: see my snippet please.

Comment: here is simple solution. Wrap the input and analogous img tag in the div and keep all sturcture of all such wrapper div same. structure i.e. containing elements and their hierarcy and write a common javascript function that will be called on every file input change and will effect the img src in the same wrapper div.